How can I convert the code below to Typescript strong typing?
I have the following function that saves my redux state to localStorage.
export const saveStateToLocalStorage = (state:any) => {
  let amazonYT = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('amazonYT')) || {};
  amazonYT = { ...amazonYT, ...state };
  localStorage.setItem('amazonYT', JSON.stringify(amazonYT));
};

Typescript is complaining about the getItem function, the error is below:

Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
(method) Storage.getItem(key: string): string | null
Returns the current value associated with the given key, or null if the given key does not exist.

How do I fix this problem?

Do you understand what the error means? Where string is expected but not provided?

TS doesn't want to let you call JSON.parse(null) (and this is an intentional prohibition, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/59457). Make sure you're parsing a string, such as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

You could do something like this:
// TODO use a better type that actually describes the data structure that you use!
type State = Record<string, unknown>

export const saveStateToLocalStorage = (state: State) => {
  const storedValue = localStorage.getItem('amazonYT')

  if (storedValue) {
    let amazonYT = JSON.parse(storedValue) as State
    amazonYT = { ...amazonYT, ...state }
    localStorage.setItem('amazonYT', JSON.stringify(amazonYT))
  }
};

The if (storedValue) guard avoids passing nulls to JSON.parse, fixing the type error.
Note that while this snippet passes type check, the types are still quite fuzzy and there is a dangerous typecast where we claim that the parsed value is State without any runtime validation.
It would be wise to use a stricter type for State depending on your actual use case and possibly use a schema validation library like zod to check that the value in localStorage is actually in the format that you expect.
